# Do i really need to have "Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool" update

Tags: windows-7, windows, anti-virus, windows-update

I got a prompt for windows update and it is update of "Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool"

Do i really need to have "Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool" update..... even if i use Kaspersky internet security?

Comment: Super User's Be Aware: There are some Windows Updates and Microsoft Software Installers that will not allow you to install them without first installing the Malicious Software Removal Tool that is currently available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do i really need to have "Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool" update..... even if i use Kaspersky internet security?

You don't "really need to have" the MSRT in the sense that you don't "really need to have" Kaspersky Internet Security. As long as you are computer literate enough you can avoid getting viruses. I have been without AV since Windows XP SP2 and haven't got a virus yet.

So in that sense, you do not need it. However, I have seen the MSRT remove viruses that commercial AV does not.

In my opinion, if you are a home user it does not hurt to run this tool. It takes 5 or 10 seconds when running automatically from Windows Update, it will only take longer if you download the standalone version and let it run for 2 or 3 hours.

Comment: +1 ...and unlike bulky “Internet Security” packages, at least MSRT won't hang around at all times sucking away your machine's performance and causing bugs whilst *still* failing to protect adequately against malware.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kaspersky Internet Security, then you don't need Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool because Kaspersky protects your system from malware, spyware and adware.